# How to add string id in url ? Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, routes, request, laravel-5.3

My link href on the view is like this :

```
<a href="{{ route('message.inbox.detail.id', ['id' => $message->id]) }}" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="fa fa-eye"></span> {{ trans('button.view') }}
</a>
```

My routes is like this :

```
Route::get('message/inbox/detail/{id}', ['as'=>'message.inbox.detail.id','uses'=>'MessageController@detail']);
```

The result of url is like this :

```
http://myshop.dev/message/inbox/detail/58cadfba607a1d2ac4000254
```

My controller is like this :

```
public function detail($id)
{
    dd($id);
}
```

If like that, I success get value of id

But I want change the result of url like this :

```
http://myshop.dev/message/inbox/detail/id/58cadfba607a1d2ac4000254
```

I want change the url like that, because on the controller I want get request like this :

```
public function detail($id, Request $request)
{
    dd($id, $request->all());
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can alter your controller to look like this:

```
public function detail(Request $request, $id)
{
    dd($id, $request);
}
```

This way the request will be injected on your method and you'll be able to access it.

Comment: It does not work. The result of `$request->all()` is empty array

Comment: Seems the url must change like this : http://myshop.dev/message/inbox/detail/id/58cadfba607a1d2ac4000254. But I don't know how can change it

Comment: So, besides I get id from `$id`, I also want get id from `Request $request` too.

Comment: `$request->all()` will be an empty array if you pass no other attribute. Try running `myshop.dev/message/inbox/detail/id/58cadfba607a1d2ac4000254?test_attribute=3`

Comment: $request->path() and explode path

Comment: @André Castelo, It can. But I want the url this : `myshop.dev/message/inbox/detail/id/58cadfba607a1d2ac4000254`. No use `?id`

Comment: @kai ogita, It is not my intention

Comment: You cannot access the ID via the `$request` variable because it is already a separate parameter. If you want to, the only way is to use `?id=` to do it.

Comment: @André Castelo, Oh, I see. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have use

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

in your controller.
And you can get like this.

```
public function detail(Request $request, $id)
{
    dd($id, $request);
}
```